# Can't upload dynamically inserted inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form and a button(link), which adds input type=file on click, using "insertBefore()" method. 
When I try to upload the form with the created input, nothing happens. But if I set the input by myself, it can be uploaded succesfully. 
Here's approximate code.

Works(I can upload the input):

```
<input type="File" name="attachEdit">
```

Doesn't work(nothing happens when I try to upload inserted input):

```
<a href="javascript: void(0);" id="attachFile" onclick="addFileInput(); return false;">Attach a file</a>
<script>  
    function addFileInput(){
        $('<input type="File" name="attachEdit">')
           .insertBefore("##attachFile");
    }
</script>
```

I want to add inputs dynamically and then upload them all.

How can I solve the problem? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are using `##attachFile` in the selector.

Comment: ## seems like a typo.

Comment: Have you checked if the generated HTML markup is currently inside the form?

Comment: @eduard: your question is not clear. Can you paste your HTML as well? Are the inputs being created dynamically, and not opening the file chooser dialog? Or you're able to choose the files, but they're not being uploaded?

Comment: @PiyushSonagara '##attachFile' - Coldfusion feature. The problem is not in this. 
I just don't understand, why inputs, inserted by 'insertBefore()' method can't be normally uploaded through submit.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are two suggestions for your code.

1. Don't use `##attachFile`. It is an invalid selector. Use `#attachFile`.
2. You can directly write `javascript:addFileInput();` in the `href` attribute of the link.

Here is a working example:

```
<!-- trucated for brevity -->
<body>
  <input type="File" name="attachEdit">
  <a href="javascript:addFileInput();" id="attachFile">Attach a file</a>

  <script>
    function addFileInput() {
      $('<input type="File" name="attachEdit">')
        .insertBefore("#attachFile");
    }
  </script>
</body>
<!-- trucated for brevity -->
```

PS: Don't forget to include jQuery in your HTML. [See this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/0oH15Ygz5Q73HSs55yZI?p=preview) for more details.